# Hostinger Free Webhosting and Sub Domain

Tags: wordpress, hosting, web-hosting

I uploaded my site @ hostinger and I choose only free hosting and free sub domain with www.mysite.16mb.com. My sites work well. My question now is, Is there an expiration for the hosting and for the sub domain? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is expiration for the free package. Though it isn't depends in time, but in visitors that should come to your website and content that should be uploaded.

If there won't be any upload/download activity, they will send you a message says your subdomain is about to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Shalev. :)